# Multithreaded update of multiple ProgressBars

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, progress-bar, invoke

I have developped an application that can process data (in my case image algorithms performed on videos). I have developed different `ProcessingMethod`s.

Sometimes several videos are processed in parallel. Each process runs in a seperate thread.

I have a GUI with several `ProgressBar`s, one for each thread that is processing data.

What is a good way to update the `ProgressBar`?

Currently, my GUI is creating all the processing threads and one `ProgressBar` for each thread. Then I pass those `ProgressBar`s to the threads, which pass them to the `ProcessingMethod`. The `ProcessingMethod` will then update the `ProgressBar` (using `Invoke()`).

I have different `ProcessingMethod`s. Within each of these methods I have copy-paste code to update the `ProgressBar`. Although I am a new to programming, I know copy-paste is not good.

What is a good way to make it better?

Comment: pls give us code, im sure it will be less than a minutes job to refactor it for u

Answer (score 3):

Create a method called `UpdateProgressBar` that will take a progress bar and its value as arguments and wrap the update with `Invoke`. You'll replace your copy-paste with calling a single function with different arguments.

Comment: By the way, people who are new to programming should try to stay away from multithreaded code. I can't imaging trying to figure out a race condition without having a firm grasp on basic techniques.

Comment: Given that you need to be in the UI thread to update the progressbar (there is only one) that will eliminate most all race conditions.

Comment: That will eliminate the progress bar race conditions, not the video processing race conditions...

Comment: From the question it seems they are working on entirely different data sets and aren't interacting at all, although I will grant you that it doesn't mean there aren't race conditions anyway.

Comment: ...though of course `BeginInvoke` would be more sensible here so that the worker thread can continue processing while the UI thread updates the control.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the BackGroundWorker component. It is intended to run threads from the GUI with safe callbacks for progressindicaton.